# Ubuntu 16.04 can't connect to http://google.com

Tags: google

Some time ago I installed ubuntu 16.04 on my computer and my sister's. My background knowledge is null, but it was relatively simple since I had an installation disk, so it was just a matter of inserting the disk and telling it to install (typical).

For a while it was all good (my connection a bit slow, but nothing more). The fact is that for some time now, my computer has stopped opening the google page (http://www.google.com // http://www.google.es).

At first, I thought it was a question of the browser (Firefox) and that with the updates there was some problem. So I installed other browsers and it remained the same.

The fact is, my sister, with the same line (16.04) can connect without any problem to google.

If someone can give some solution (simple if possible since my knowledge are void) I would be very grateful. The truth is that it is a nuisance because the translator of gogle comes to me from pearls and, of course, I can not access it.

Comment: Use 16.10 or newer.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: Why? Ubuntu 16.04 is going to be supported for at least another 4 years.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The user can't connect to any sites.  Since he can't connect to google, it's almost certainly a DNS problem or an issue with IPv6.

Comment: @L.D.James: Yes that's possible but we don't really know much except that `google.com` is unreachable. We don't know whether other sites are reachable or anything else. It could also be a kernel upgrade breaking the (out-of-tree) networking adapter driver or a faulty Network Manager upgrade (like we had last year).

Comment: The user tested two different google sites on his computer.  When checking for connection issues I always try Google as a default way of seeing if the internet works.  I use `ping -c10 8.8.8.8`.  I always tell my clients to try to bring up three different web sites with one of them being  `google.com` when they think they are having a problem.  He indicated that a family member doesn't have problems accessing the pages.  So that tells me that it's his computer.  The working sometimes and being extremely slow has happened to me many times of which it turned out that disabling IPv6 resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google Page loading slow or not at all:**

There are two common reasons for the problem that you have expressed.

Add a reliable name server to your `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

Add this as the first uncommented line of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

You can make this a permanent configuration by added the line to your `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` file.

Some systems have a problem with the IPv6 resolution.  You can disable the IPv6 with:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Append this:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run this command:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Details at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4

You can resort the IPv6 back to it's default state by removing the appended lines from the `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Voy a probar la solución que me da y veremos que pasa.  ¡¡¡Crucemos los dedos!!!

Comment: It's a pleasure!  Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: Problema resuelto. Me costó un poco editar el archivo en cuestión, pero al final, lo conseguí. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @MiguelBarrientosGarcía You're welcome.  I'm glad it worked.  Please consider clicking on the Gray check mark to show the steps worked.  This way others in the community with a similar issue will see how to resolve their problem.